# Bug when I open a Bluetooth setting

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I want to get response if user click yes , that he want to get his phone discoverable. When an ansewer is yes I want to start new Activity, but when a user open a setting bluetooth my application is open new activity (and this is a bug)

This is what I do :

```
    private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver2 = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();

            if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED)) {

                int mode = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_SCAN_MODE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

                switch (mode) {
                    case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE:
                        Intent serverIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DeviceListActivity.class);
//                        startActivityForResult(serverIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
//                        showProgressbar();
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE:
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_NONE:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    };


 IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter();
    filter2.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
    filter2.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    filter2.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver2, filter2);
```

Comment: Post error logs please this is most important part if you wanna help from somebody !

Comment: @NikolaLukic when I have open a activity DeviceList and when  open android setting bloutooth my application open another DeviceList activity